# set default option for select drop down

Tags: php, kohana

views.php

```
<?= Form::select('em'.$user, array('1' => 'option1', '2' => 'option2'), '', array('class'=>"select-input feed-select-dropdown myselect", 'id'=>'em'.$user, 'style'=>'width:124px; margin-left:438px;'));?>
```

In this select drop down,how to set the `option2` as selected by default.

Comment: according to the documentation: [kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Form#select](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Form#select), the third parameter can be the value of the 'option' that you want selected by default. You passed '' (empty string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do it-

```
<?= Form::select('em'.$user, array('1' => 'option1', '2' => 'option2'),'2', array('class'=>"select-input feed-select-dropdown myselect", 'id'=>'em'.$user, 'style'=>'width:124px; margin-left:438px;'));?>
```